# Como inserto a una tabla SQL la fecha automáticamente desde PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Quiero insertar la fecha automáticamente en cuanto le den al botón submit.

vi estas opciones: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP y DEFAULT (getdate()

Este en mi insert, los demás datos los ingreso mediante POST inclusive la fecha y todo funciona bien, pero quiero que la fecha se genere automáticamente, sin que el usuario pueda ingresarla.

```php
$insertar = "INSERT INTO asesoria Values ('', '$matricula', '$nombre', '$fecha', '$tipo', '$para', '$tema', '$hora_inicio', '$hora_final', '$genero')";
```

En el apartado fecha como lo sustituyo?

Comment: En la consulta solo cambia `'$fecha',` por `NOW(),` y ten en cuenta que no va entre comillas.

Comment: I love you, forever and ever, jjejeej. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Esto dependerá el formato de fecha  de tu sql pero la respuesta seria así:

```html
$insertar = "INSERT INTO asesoria Values ('', '$matricula', '$nombre', date("Y-m-d"), '$tipo', '$para', '$tema', '$hora_inicio', '$hora_final', '$genero')";
```

Si quieres guardar la hora (y si tu campo en la db lo permite) cambia `date("Y-m-d")` por `date("Y-m-d H:i:ss)`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función NOW() de MySql:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO asesoria Values ('', '$matricula', '$nombre', NOW(), '$tipo', '$para', '$tema', '$hora_inicio', '$hora_final', '$genero')";
```

Pero yo normalmente prefiero que la fecha me la de PHP, porque suelo definir la time zone para mi aplicación PHP. De esa forma, me aseguro de que en la base de datos meto la fecha y hora conforme a la hora de mi aplicación:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO asesoria Values ('', '$matricula', '$nombre', '" . date('Y-m-d') . "', '$tipo', '$para', '$tema', '$hora_inicio', '$hora_final', '$genero')";
```

Si tu campo fuera de tipo datetime en vez de date, reemplaza 'Y-m-d' por 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

Nota: Construir las instrucciones SQL insertando las variables directamente en la cadena es peligroso, dejas tu código vulnerable a ataques por inyección SQL. Tienes que escaparlas adecuandamente, o utilizar prepared statements.